# how to make a floating div that will float at the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a floating div that will sit at the bottom of the page if bottom of current page is above window screen otherwise it will sit just above windows screen taskbar and if we scroll the page it will maintain its current position.

Comment: Aren't you looking for position: fixed? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to use `position: fixed`

```css
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uw8f9/

Comment: use z-index to make the element appear on top of every other elements on the page

Comment: position: sticky is another good, more recent option for this, if you need the floating element to have a width based on some % of its parent. (A sticky element does need at least one sibling element after it, but you can just make a filler div)

Answer (score -5):

try this style for your floating DIV

```
{
display:block;
position:absolute;
float:left;
bottom:0px;
left:20px;
}
```

Comment: `position:absolute;` and then `float:left;`? Seriously??